# showing data from excel to datagridview using c#

Tags: c#, sql, excel, datagridview

I'm using Excel as a database, I want to show all columns in a DataGridView using c#, the problem is I have a column which formated as hours (hh:mm) so when i want to show data in the DataGridView this column appears like this (30/12/1899 15:20) but all I want is 15:20
[excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSfm5.png)

[DataGridView image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6jcO.png)
my code :

```
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Inf, Date,Entrie, Sortie,Coupe,Préparation,Ford,EB,B7,Qualité, Production, Logistique, Ingenierie, Maintenance, Fournisseurs, Administration, Motifs, Traitement, Quantité, Commentaire From [" + sheetName + "] where Matricule =" + textBox4.Text;
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            con.Open();
                            oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            oda.Fill(dt);
                            con.Close();
                            dt_All.Merge(dt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the DataTable as the data source for the DataGridView set the format for that column e.g.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm";
```